# Trouble setting up closures for class methods

Tags: php, closures, lambda

I am architecting out a class and so far have something roughly like the following

in main.php

```
$coolObject = new CoolObject(true);

foreach($array as $key=>$val)
{
    $coolObject->doFunction($val);
}
```

then inside of CoolObject:

```
class CoolObject
{
    private $_useFunction;

    public function __construct($useFoo)
    {
        //THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
        if($useFoo){
            $this->_useFunction = $this->_foo();
        }
        else{
            $this->_useFunction = $this->_bar();
        }
    }

    public function doFunction($values)
    {
        $this->_useFunction($values);
    }

    private function foo($values){
        //do stuff
    }

    private function bar($values){
        //do other stuff
    }
}
```

I realize I could put an if statement or switch into doFunction that could handle this functionality, but since I'm not hip on closures/lamdas I wasn't sure if this is the right situation for them or if I'm just totally off base

Comment: PHP is not JS. Try to read about variable variable : http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: Also, you could probably solve this with inheritance

Comment: @Juan I was thinking inheritance would probably get this, but since it's only one function that's different between the two versions I thought I would see if this was a good use for storing functions in a variable, and if that's the right use of closure since the concept is still fairly new to me. If I can't make it work, I absolutely will fall back on using inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve (as far as I know) are function pointers in PHP.

You should really take a look in: [Array Pointer to a function in PHP](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/953482)

I still think inheritance will be the easiest/cleaniest way to solve this.

So you would probably end with:

class CoolObject
{
    private $_useFunction;

```
public function __construct($useFoo)
{
    //THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
    if($useFoo){
        $this->_useFunction = 'foo';
    }
    else{
        $this->_useFunction = 'bar';
    }
}

public function doFunction($values)
{
//Edited as @newacct corrects
$this->$_useFunction($values); 
}

private function foo($values){
    //do stuff
}

private function bar($values){
    //do other stuff
}
```

}

Comment: This is what I was looking for (because it came up once before, for me).  I will still probably use inheritance though.  Thanks for the help Juan.

Comment: instead of `call_user_func($this->$_useFunction , $values);` you can just do `$this->$_useFunction($values);`